# How could I know if all my modules are loaded in prism 4?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-4

I have a WPF Desktop application using PRISM, there are 12 modules which do not depend on each other , every time i start the shell, modules are been loaded , the point is that I would like to know which module loads at the last so I could start an action. How could I determine this ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to trigger the action when all modules are loaded?  Do you have a place in Your code where all modules are loaded? Or can You log the initialization of the modules?

Comment: I like to raise an event when all of my modules are loaded. the application does not know how many modules are going to be loaded, the modules are located in a directory ".\modules".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override Bootstrapper.InitializeModules,  call base, and then ACTION!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on erikH's answer (thank you, btw), assuming that you are deriving from the default UnityBootstrapper, here is the order in which the typically overridden methods are called:

```
//0
public override void Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration)
{
    base.Run(runWithDefaultConfiguration);
    //this is our last opportunity to hook into the PRISM bootstrapping sequence; at this point every very other base-overridden 
    //method has been executed
}

//1
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
    ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
    //add modules...
}

//2
protected override void ConfigureContainer() 
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    //register everything with the container...
}

//3
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return Container.Resolve<ShellView>();      //resolve your root component
}

//4
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();
    App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
    App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}

//5
protected override void InitializeModules()
{
    base.InitializeModules();
}
```

Note that this applies to PRISM 4 and 5